# How to add ACF Gutinburg block data to custom Pages?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gutenberg-blocks

I want to create custom ACF gutinburg block for my front-page.php  I've register ACF block in Fuction.php like this:

```
 function acf_portfolio_item_block() {
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block') ) {
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name'              => 'front-page',
            'title'             => __('Front Page'),
            'description'       => __('A custom block for Front Page'),
            'render_template'   => get_template_directory().'front-page.php',
            'category'          => 'layout',
            'icon'              => 'excerpt-view',
            'keywords'          => array( 'front','front-page','home' ),            
        ));
        
    }
}

add_action('acf/init', 'acf_portfolio_item_block');
```

[create Field Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW7hD.png)

The HTML of my block on front-page.php:

```
 <?php
$title1 = get_field( 'title' );
$subtitle1 = get_field( 'subtitle' );
$description1 = get_field( 'description' );
?>
    <section class="hero-sec">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-5 hero-col-1">
                    <h1 class="fw-bold">
                    <?php echo $title1; ?> 
                    </h1>
                    <h1>
                   <?php echo $subtitle1; ?>
                    </h1>   
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $description1;?>   
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

but it's not working not showing data on front-page .php

Comment: Please fix your formatting and show us what you have tried so far to fix the problem. Also include some logs or anything that helps us to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the the confusion. Basically, I want to register custom Gutinburg block for my front-page.  I just follow this post but not working for me.
https://torquemag.io/2020/01/create-gutenberg-block-with-acf/

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Any useful infos there? Have you checked if you hook gets called?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Yes hook gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The `allowed_block_types` filter hook in WordPress allows you to specify what blocks are allowed in certain conditions.

Since you're using **ACF** when creating your custom block and you name your block `name => 'front-page'` the final block name would be: `acf/front-page`

```
function wp123_allowed_block_types($allowed_block_types, $post) {

  if(is_front_page()) {
    return [
      'acf/front-page'
    ];
  }

  return $allowed_block_types;

}
add_filter('allowed_block_types', 'wp123_allowed_block_types', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks dear, I just add this function but still didn't get values from acf block..